# Preload data on Heroku first time creation

Tags: django, heroku

I create a new deployment for every new customer on Heroku platform.

However as my app gets deployed to Heroku some default data should be uploaded. Each time I update - existing data should remain.

What is my best option? Thanks!

Comment: You could create a management command to get your data into the database. Those can be executed by running **heroku run python manage.py <name_of_your_command>** in your cli

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-management-commands/

@dentemm I guess you are talking about this one? Thanks

Comment: Correct, I use those all the time. You're welcome!